# Custom node REPL with typescript and ts-node

Tags: node.js, shell, read-eval-print-loop, ts-node

I want to create a custom node REPL and make it work with typescript.
As stated on ts-node documentations

> nodeEval
>
> nodeEval(code: string, context: any, _filename: string, callback: (err: null | > Error, result?: any) => any): void
>
> Defined in src/repl.ts:91
>
> eval implementation compatible with node's REPL API
>
> Can be used in advanced scenarios if you want to manually create your own node > REPL instance and delegate eval to this ReplService.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> import {start} from 'repl'; 
> const replService: tsNode.ReplService = ...; // assuming you have already created a ts-node ReplService
> const nodeRepl = start({eval: replService.eval});
> ```
>
> Blockquote
>
> Parameters
>
> code: string
>
> context: any
>
> _filename: string
>
> callback: (err: null | Error, result?: any) => any
>
> (err: null | Error, result?: any): any
>
> Parameters
>
> err: null | Error
>
> Optional result: any
>
> Returns any
>
> Returns void

`nodeEval` is a member of the `ReplService` class created with `createRepl` method. It seems to be compatible with the `eval` parameter that can be passed down to the `start` method.

So I wrote this:

```
import { start } from "repl";
import * as tsnode from "ts-node";

const tsNodeConfig = {
  compilerOptions: {
    target: "ES2017",
    module: "commonjs",
  },
};

tsnode.register({
  compilerOptions: {
    target: "ES2017",
    module: "CommonJS",
  },
});

const tsrepl: tsnode.ReplService = tsnode.createRepl({
  stdin: process.stdin,
  stdout: process.stdout,
});

const { nodeEval } = tsrepl;

tsnode.register(tsNodeConfig);

start({
  prompt: "$  ",
  ignoreUndefined: true,
  eval: nodeEval,
});
```

I then run the code in the terminal where I created this repl.ts file and run `ts-node repl.ts` the shell starts, but it gives me this error when I enter any value like `let foo = "bar"`:

```bash
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (node:readline:1216:14)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (node:readline:864:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (node:readline:487:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at REPLServer.onLine (node:repl:893:10)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (node:domain:432:12)
    at bound (node:domain:421:15)
    at REPLServer.nodeEval (/Users/WAW/Documents/Projects/noiz-network-state/node_modules/ts-node/src/repl.ts:262:7)
    at handleError (/Users/WAW/Documents/Projects/noiz-network-state/node_modules/ts-node/src/repl.ts:271:18)
$
```

If i pass down the object without the eval parameter, like this

```
start({
  prompt: "$  ",
  ignoreUndefined: true
});
```

the repl works as a node repl and it doesn't evaluate typescript code like `type foo = string`..

any idea??

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution, in fact there is need to configure the `ts-node repl service` properly in order for this to work.

First we need to import

- `repl` from node packages
- `ts` from `typescript` npm package
- `ts-node` from  package

```
import repl from "repl";
import ts from "typescript";
import * as tsnode from "ts-node";
```

then we need to create a ts-node repl service like this:

```
const replService: tsnode.ReplService = tsnode.createRepl();
```

now we can actually create a service thanks to the `evalAwarePartialHost` member that is's inside the `replService` that we just created:

```
const service = tsnode.create({ ...replService.evalAwarePartialHost });
```

we then set the `ts` member of the `service` to be `ts` that we imported:

```
service.ts = ts;
```

now we have to set the service in the ts-node repl:

```
replService.setService(service);
```

now it's time to create the actual repl server:

```
const replServer = repl.start({
  prompt: "$  ",
  ignoreUndefined: true,
  eval: replService.nodeEval,
});
```

the entire code looks like this:

```
import repl from "repl";
import ts from "typescript";
import * as tsnode from "ts-node";

// Create a ts-node replService
const replService: tsnode.ReplService = tsnode.createRepl();
const service = tsnode.create({ ...replService.evalAwarePartialHost });
service.ts = ts;
replService.setService(service);

// create a node-repl server
const replServer = repl.start({
  prompt: "$  ",
  ignoreUndefined: true,
  eval: replService.nodeEval,
});

// setup environment
replServer.setupHistory(".log", () => {});
```

hope this can be helpfull for someone else!!

=)

Comment: can you setup a gist to run this script? I was tried setup ts project from scratch however, it failed to load repl